# How to push values of formGroup which is inisde a formArray

Tags: angular5, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I have my significantOwners as an array and I have address as a formGroup, Once the service gives me data, I would like to to push values obtained from the service into the form, How would I do that ?

```js
this.significantOwnersForm = fb.group({
    significantOwners: this.buildSignificantOwnerArray()
});

buildSignificantOwnerArray() {
    this.significantOwners = this.fb.array([this.buildSignificantOwnerGroup()]);

    return this.significantOwners;
}

buildSignificantOwnerGroup() {
    return this.fb.group({
        name: '',
        address: this.fb.group({
            addressLine1: '',
            addressLine2: '',
            addressLine3: '',
            addressLine4: '',
            addressLine5: '',
            city: '',
            state: '',
            postalCode: '',
            countryCode: ''
        })
    });
}

setSelectedSignificantOwnersInformation() {
    let selectedMerchantsSignificantOwners = this.merchantInfo[this.selected[0].merchantNumber].significantOwners;
    let significantOwnersFGs = selectedMerchantsSignificantOwners.map(owner => this.fb.group(owner));
    let significantOwnerFormArray = this.fb.array(significantOwnersFGs);

    this.significantOwnersForm.setControl('significantOwners', significantOwnerFormArray);
}
```

I get an error 
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'significantOwners -> 1 -> address -> addressLine1'

It can't find anything insidse the address.

Updated: 
Showing the error

```
MdfComponent.html:1866 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'significantOwners -> 0 -> address -> addressLine1'
    at _throwError (forms.js:2432)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:2300)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:6658)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:7308)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:7221)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12365)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13893)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13836)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14729)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14670)
```

Comment: Is the error correct and looking for `significantOwnersForm -> 0 -> adress -> addressLine1`. If so, maybe it is because `address` is incorrectly spelled as `adress`.

Comment: I am sorry I typed in the error, but I updated, there is actually no spelling  mistake

Comment: I still havent resolved the issue. could someone help me ?

Comment: Can you provide the **exact** error message that you are getting? Somebody may have an idea when getting the exact details of it

Comment: I have provided the exact error message

Comment: @Vignesh - Can you also provide the stack trace of the error - it this a compilation or runtime error?

Comment: Can you tell us how many items the selectedMerchantsSignificantOwners array has - 1 or 2?

Comment: @ChrisWhite, I have updated the error I get, and as far as the number of items i get , it is depenedent on what the service returns, but the one that I was trying had 4 objects in the array .